# Where is the saying "A for away" from?

Tags: idioms, popular-refrains, dialects

I have recently picked up the saying "A for away" (meaning, we are good to go/ready to go). I am English but live in South Africa and watch American TV, so I have no idea where this saying is from. Is it a global saying or regional to one of my "zones"?

Comment: I have never heard of this before. Can you provide an example of it in a complete sentence or, better yet, an exchange of dialogue?

Comment: For clarity, I assume the meaning is "we are in grade 'A' condition/readiness on the question of starting the activity/journey". It took me a moment to parse the phrase as I've never heard it before (in BrE).

Comment: Hello, Mary, and welcome to EL&U. Could you possibly provide a little more context? Where did you hear it?

Comment: @JasonBassford me neither. I've never heard it in BrE. We really need context to comment further.

Comment: Is the "a" in "a for away" pronounced to rhyme with "away" or as a schwa ("uh")?

Comment: @schoover I thought of the possible rhyme too.

Comment: @shoover It's rhyming. I'm G for Good, I'm D for Done, I'm A for Away, ...

Comment: possibly it’s really “A for aweigh” from “Anchors aweigh”

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it lacks clarity and is in desperate need of context. Having read the answers and comments, I suspect that jimm101 had the most likely answer when he remarked *It's rhyming. I'm G for Good, I'm D for Done, I'm A for Away, ... – jimm101 Jul 2 '19 at 20:54*

Comment: I have never heard it in the US.

Answer (score 0):

In sports, half of a team's games are played on the home field ("home games") and the other half are played on the opponent team's field ("away games").  In this context, it can be said that

> H is for home, A is for away

This seems similar to "A is for Apple," which appears in children's alphabet picture books.  This phrase is given as a mnemonic to medical students, to help them remember that arteries lead blood away from the heart.

Your definition, *we are good to go/ready to go*, fits well in the general, non-technical and non-sports sentences I see on the internet, that include this expression.

It seems especially common in South African, but I also came across it in things coming from the UK and Australia.

**I have never heard this in the US.**

I could not find this expression in any dictionary.  Among others, I tried Cambridge and Oxford.

Answer (score 0):

It may be regional.

See https://pigcasso.myshopify.com/products/a-for-away,

where a business in South Africa sells paintings done (supposedly) by a pig.  One of them is called “A for Away,” but it’s sold out.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The two previous answers seem to misunderstand the usage of the expression. As the question already provides the meaning –

> we are good to go / ready to go

– it seems likely that the expression is a stylistic combination of the normal meaning of "away" with a borrowed construction using the first letter of the key word.

*In other words, "we're A for away" is like a cross between "**we're off and away**" and "**we're G for Go**".*

I don't think this is a particularly regionalised usage, although to my ear it has a certain AmE flavour to it, perhaps deriving from NASA and military styles or Hollywood tropes.

To take the two components separately:

### off and away

[**away**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/away)
**adverb**

> 1. on the way : ALONG
>
>    - *get **away** early*
> 2. from this or that place
>
>    - *go **away***
>
> **adjective**
>
> 1. absent from a place : GONE
>
>    - ***away*** for the weekend
>
> [Source: Merriam-Webster Dictionary]

The expression "we're A for away" is likely meant in the sense of the idiom *off and away*, which is often used to emphasise the relief or excitement that a journey, escape, race or game has just started. Published examples of that idiom include:

> - *I did not linger. Getting swiftly off the mark, I dived for the door-handle, and was off and away, banging the door behind me.*—[P.G. Wodehouse](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=kJrYBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA17&dq=%22off+and+away%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit3Zbiq-_iAhWVYysKHXb1DUc4FBDoAQhdMAk#v=onepage&q=%22off%20and%20away%22&f=false)
> - *Congratulations! / Today is your day. / You're off to Great Places! / You're off and away!*—[Dr. Seuss](https://genius.com/Dr-seuss-oh-the-places-youll-go-excerpt-annotated)
> - *I gave them each a taste of the goose, and I was off and away. None of the others wanted to follow me.*—[Jill Whalen](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=fzXVBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT169&dq=%22off+and+away%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF-9S7q-_iAhXRV30KHeX8Ag04ChDoAQhKMAY#v=onepage&q=%22off%20and%20away%22&f=false)
> - *'So we're off?' she asked, backing away towards the front door. Suddenly she **so** wanted to be off. Off and away. Far away.*—[Ally Blake](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=HcMEBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT84&dq=%22off+and+away%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF-9S7q-_iAhXRV30KHeX8Ag04ChDoAQgtMAE#v=onepage&q=%22off%20and%20away%22&f=false)

### G for Go

> [**go**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go)
>   **adjective**
>
> functioning properly : being in good and ready condition
>
> - *declared all systems **go***

A famous usage is from the film Apollo 13, with the line "Launch Control, this is Houston. We are go for launch!" ([see *minute 34*](https://www.apollo13minute.com/cm/episodes/minute-034-we-are-go-for-launch/))

Adding a reference to the first letter of the key word, as in *G for go*, is a way of emphasising the word. A published example is:

- *Remi flashed me a thumbs-up. "You catch that, Pump? Another fifteen minutes. Otherwise, all systems are G for Go."*—[Tom Wayman](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=skiMuuaTry0C&pg=PA213&dq=%22are+g+for+go%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS77Pas-_iAhWYWX0KHadSCEwQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22are%20g%20for%20go%22&f=false)

Comment: Does not answer the question. Does not contain valid and necessary reference.

Comment: @Zincha thank you for your feedback, it’s much appreciated. To help me improve my answer, which points do you feel are lacking a relevant reference?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/340007)

Comment: @jimm101 please refer to my 4th paragraph starting “I don’t think” and tell me how that’s not answering the question.